# Question about a set of distinct odd integers and their least common multiple

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, divisor-sum

Let $S=\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ be some set of distinct odd integers greater than 1, such that $\forall  x_i\in S$ it holds that $x_i<\sqrt{\text{lcm} (x_1,x_2,...x_n)}$ and $x_i\mid \text{lcm} (x_1,x_2,...x_n)$ (where $\mid$ means "divides").

I was wondering if:

is it possible that $1+\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k = x_ix_j$, where $x_i\in S$ and $x_j\in S$, $x_ix_j >\sqrt{\text{lcm}\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}}$ and $x_ix_j\mid \text{lcm} (x_1,x_2,...x_n)$ ?

I am trying to find an example of this equality, but have not been able yet. I am wondering if this kind of equality is even possible, but I am stuck when trying to prove if such a set is possible or not. Any help on this would be really welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(It's late and it might be possible that this doesn't work. If so, let me know and I'd delete it.)

Show that this works:

$ S = \{3, 5, 9, 21, 25, 27, 35, 63\}$
$LCM = 4725, \sqrt{LCM} \approx 68.7$
$x_i = 9, x_j = 21$.

Comment: it works perfectly! Thanks for providing the example! Could you share which was your method for obtaining it?

Comment: @JuanMoreno Given our history, if you share your thoughts which show you've spend more than a few seconds thinking about it, I'd reply. There are lots of hints in the numbers that were chosen. E.g. start by factoring 4725.